# Installing Ubuntu-sdk, issue with lxd on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-sdk, lxd

I'm trying to install Linux SDK using `apt install ubuntu-sdk`. I get error about dependencies which end up with `lxd`:

Running `apt install lxd` result in the following error:

```
*lxd : Depends: lxd-client (= 2.0.11-0ubuntu1~16.04.4) but
3.0.3-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 is to be installed*
```

Update/upgrade has been done and the system is up to date.

I have no idea how to solve this.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`ubuntu-sdk` is not supported anymore by Canonical since they stopped the effort for Ubuntu Phone.
But the Ubuntu Phone effort is continued by [the Ubports team](https://ubports.com).
The Ubports team though, does not use the `ubuntu-sdk` either.

*[Clickable](http://clickable.bhdouglass.com/en/latest/) is a meta-build system for Ubuntu Touch applications that allows you to compile, build, test and publish click packages and provides various templates to get you started with app development. It is currently the easiest and most convenient way of building click packages for Ubuntu Touch. You can use any code editor or IDE that you choose and build your apps from the commandline with Clickable.*

*Alternatively there is the old Ubuntu SDK IDE. Be aware that it is no longer supported by Canonical, and UBports has chosen to not support it either due to lack of manpower.*

*You can still install the SDK IDE in Ubuntu 16.04, but it is not guaranteed to work correctly.*

Source: http://docs.ubports.com/en/latest/appdev/

Comment: Thank for answer but I don't understand the relation with my question. I do not use a phone but a PC.

Comment: @fpiette `ubuntu-sdk` is now unsupported. The package was last updated in 2016. It was based on Qt-Creator, with addons and customization to make it create packages for the Ubuntu Phone.

Comment: To clarify, the `ubuntu-sdk` was meant to be used to create Ubuntu Mobile applications. It is not a generic Ubuntu SDK (it is a customized Qt Creator package). If you want to develop software, use the latest version of Qt Creator instead.

Answer (score 0):

[The unmet package is available on recommended updates repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/lxd-client), this explain why `apt` is unable to found the requested package.

You have to enable it.

1. Open Software & Updates
2. Navigate to `Updates` tab.
3. Enable **Recommended updates (`xenial-updates`)**.

[image]

Then, run `sudo apt install ubuntu-sdk` again, this should work.

If the default repositories don't work, you can try use additional repo.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-sdk
```

This also stated in [Official Ubuntu's guide to SDK](https://docs.ubuntu.com/phone/en/platform/sdk/installing-the-sdk), you should be able to perfectly install it then.

Comment: The settings where already like you specified. I get the error: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-sdk : Depends: ubuntu-sdk-ide but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. If i install ubuntu-sdk-ide, I get similar error about lxd. The when installing lxd I get the error I reported in my question.

Comment: @fpiette Sorry, I couldn't reproduce the same error in my Ubuntu 16.04, maybe try enable all the addditional PPA and run the command again?

Comment: I'm kind of a newbie in Ubuntu :-( How can find other PPA and install it?

Comment: @fpiette I already edited my answer, please do try it out.

Comment: I finally found the solution: apt-get remove lxd-client then apt-get install ubuntu-sdk. I have yet to check if the SDK is correctly installed but at least the installation went to the end without apparent problem. I will report the final status here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's not yet the complete solution. Now there is no complain about lxd, but when I run ubuntu-sdk from the command line, I get a QTCreator error: "The container backend setup detection failed. The detection tool did not return in time. Please try again."

Comment: I believe that's for [new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) as your main problem has been solved.

Comment: Thanks for recommandation. Done here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140059/the-container-backend-setup-detection-failed-the-detection-tool-did-not-return

Comment: @fpiette If you find it helpful, consider accept this answer by clicking grey checkmark to turn into green checkmark ✅.